# Why does my board start smoking when I put in a higher battery same voltage?

Tags: voltage, batteries, pcb, lipo

I just got my custom PCB in the post from PCBWAY.

Plugged in small battery I got with adafruit only 2000mah at 3.7V (PKCELL LP803860)
and showed the LED light to show it was being powered so I thought great its working.

However upon then connecting a battery I ordered off of alibaba.
(EWT LP10048166) same voltage at 3.7V and larger size at 20AH (20000mah)

My JST 2-PH connector starts smoking.

Anyone know why this is happening as I would of thought this of worked out fine with same voltage and larger battery size.

The first part of the board which is dealing with the battery is in simple terms adafruit's 1000C Powerboost which I've added into my design. So its designed to take in 3.7V and then convert that to 5V which is the majority voltage that the components on my board require. The purpose of the PCB in conjunction with a Pi camera v2 module, Compute module 3, 3 ultrasonic sensors & a cree LED is to act as a visual awareness system for the visually impaired so the reason I'm using a 20Ah battery is I require the system have enough power to maintain up to 10 hours of use per day.

Didn't realise the JST connector is rated up to 2 Amps perhaps that might be the reason for some smoking if a 20 amp battery is connected directly to it. Was speaking to a friend of mine and she suggested it could be some of the components on the board might have their resistance change due to the higher amp current. Didn't need to worry about + & - as the connector only allows one way for the pins to meet.

Here's a picture of the larger battery

[image]

In Response to Daniel Tork here is the schematic for the affected section of the board.

[image]

And here is from board view in Eagle
[image]

Followed exactly what MartinF posted in his new edit and that fixed the problem.
Turns out the polarity was reversed on the battery's JST connector. With care managed to pop them out and switch them around. Inserted into the board and the LED on the board went on and no smoke.

Comment: Switched + and -?

Comment: They likely designed the circuit taking the impedance of the battery into account, such that it acts as a series resistor, limiting the current. Changing the impedance of the battery lowers this resistor such your circuit is able to take more current (If it so desires) which in this case I would assume so. I think you may have been nuked by non-limited in-rush current or your LEDs sinking too much current.

Comment: Okay cheers for this information. I know that the board still works as after pulling out the battery causing the issue I inserted a previous 2ah battery and that worked a charm.

Comment: @sidA30: That doesn't sound plausible to me. Inrush current is usually only a spike, especially since there are no motors or that sort of stuff. Smoke only comes after a while, not because of spikes. Also the Adafruit website suggests that the 1000C board is able to handle bigger batteries.

Comment: @MartinF You know capacitance has large in-rush right? Like an MCU, displays ect, which is why a lot of SMPS have soft-starts. My point was primarily aimed at the impedance of the battery, not the amp hours of the thing.

Comment: @MarcBrooks The inrush may be a spike, but still carries a lot of energy because it's duration is > 0. I've seen FETs go up in smoke because of it.

Comment: @sidA30: I just thought it would take a while before a 2A rated connector would start smoking. I'd think it would take more than a spike, more like a second or so? And after the spike, wouldn't the thing stop smoking? But I don't know for how long it was smoking of course. Datasheet of the TPS61090 used in the 1000C states it has a current limiter for Isw of max. 2500mA, and a startup current limiter of 0,4 Isw. Wouldn't it take more than 2,5A to make a 2A connector smoke? I know about capacitance inrush, but on a current limited chip? I don't know. But I might be completely wrong! No offence.

Comment: In-rush current often destroys the internals of a components which causes a short circuit, so it will burn for as long as the short stays there. This is rather than a constant DC fault like your thinking of.

Comment: Current limiting takes it's time. E.g. TI samples current every 250us. In worst case you'd have 500us (+TI boni) inrush current

Comment: Would be better if you could actually _edit_ the post instead of tacking on numerous "Edit 1:, Edit 2:" etc.

Comment: I agree with pipe: please add a schematic instead of trying to describe your setup with words. I can't figure out where is that connector placed. If you clarify things, Marc Brooks, your question can turn out to be something interesting.

Comment: @sidA30 "In-rush current often *destroys* [...]" So if a FET would switch on a huge capacitor, the initial surge (short) would destroy it, and if the FET would short-out because of that. The high current following the short-out (long) would make it smoke, right? Now OP mentioned that his board still works. So the failure was non-destructive. So the smoke could come from the short inrush current *alone*. At 600kHz I assume current is measured at least once per cycle, so can a pulse of 1.7us max. cause a *connector* to smoke? I'd expect a spark or some trace would act as a fuse rather than that?

Comment: Should I start a new question about this specific ussue? I'm super interested in what would come out, and I'd love to learn, even if I'm wrong! But it's also sort-of related to the question OP asked. Or maybe we should move the discussion to chat? Or maybe there's not much more to say about it? What would be best practice, since I'm only on EE.SE for 6 days now...?

Comment: I would not focus on OP's question as it lacks information to actually deal with his issue, eg, circuit diagrams. As for your question, you could for sure ask 'How does in-rush current damage circuits' (again, I dont know if this is what OPs problem is), im sure you will get some good awnsers. As for information, TI has some easy to read notes on the topic here http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva670a/slva670a.pdf

Comment: And yes, if you were to switch current above the FET's peak current rating you could damage it, if you think of the FETs internal impedance as a trace refered to in the link above, you will understand why.

Comment: Sure give me a sec. Will upload the schematic section for the part of the board that was smoking.

Comment: @sidA30: Sorry, but looking at several of your answers in our little 'discussion' here, I think you might misunderstand my whole point. But I'll rest my case here, since the OP's question is answered. I'll think about posting a question about unrush vs. smoke :-). Thanks anyway for giving me good input to think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- If your board was designed to work with 3.7V in the first place, then connecting the larger capacity battery should not be a problem since both batteries are 3,7V. Was your board designed for 3,7V?
- As @Alexander already commented, check if you accidently switched the + and -
- The 'JST' connector is rated upto 2Amp, so quite some current is flowing to make it smoke. Is there a fuse on the board? Is there a reverse protection diode on the board? Did you try to power up the board again with the smaller capacity battery?
- Since specs on websites like Alibaba are not the most reliable, you could check the voltage coming out of your battery, and check if it's really (close to) 3,7V. I couldn't find the battery number you posted. There are lots of batteries called 'AWT', but then still no results for that number. (20AH is huge btw.)

---

Edit: Proof that you have the polarity reversed!

So I took a close look at your battery, and at the 1000C module and at the JST 2-PH connector.

[image: JST 2-PH]

This is a closeup of a generic JST 2-PH connector. Don't mind the colors of the wires as this is just a picture from the Internet. What's important is: You can clearly see that when the 'springs' that hold the contacts in the connector are on top, the '|' and two 'bumps' that hold the connector in the receptacle are on the bottom.

[image: Adafruit 1000C]

This is a closeup of the Adafruit 1000C module. The '|' and the bumps are on top, so the 'springs' must be on the bottom. With the '|' on top, the + is on the right. Put the '|' on the bottom, and thus the *'springs' on top, the + would be on the LEFT*.

[image: Large battery connector]

Now here's a closeup of the picture you posted in your question. The 'springs' are clearly on top, and you can see on the bottom there is one of the 'bumps', that are on the same side of the '|'. So the '|' is on the bottom. 'Springs' on top, + should be on the LEFT, but is on the RIGHT!

So your polarity is indeed reversed! You can carefully lift the 'springs' and take the contacts out. Then you can put them back in the right place. Be careful not to bend the 'springs' too far, as they are only plastic, and easly break off. Also make sure you don't accidentally short-circuit the battery when both contacts are out.

Hope this helps!

Update: I just saw they actually have a warning on [their website](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-powerboost-1000c-load-share-usb-charge-boost/pinouts) for third party batteries with the polarity reversed!

How do you intend to charge the battery? Via the 1000C? Because that module can only charge with 1000mA max., so charging your battery (when completely discharged) will take more than 24 hours. I don't even know if you can charge a Li-Ion/Li-Po battery with less than 0.5C. But that's a completely different topic anyway...

Comment: It also depends on the application. A 20Ah battery can provide a lot more power than a tiny 2Ah cell. If you switch a motor or smth. you can easily reach some kA as SCD current.

Comment: You're right. Since OP didn't mention anything but a simple LED, I didn't assume big consumers. I wonder what his board is supposed to do with 20AH of battery capacity... What do you mean with SCD current? Do you mean *inrush* current?

Comment: Yeah, inrush current. Im stuck with TI terminology and there it's called short circuit discharge current

Comment: @MarcBrooks Please add this info about your application to your question

Comment: @MarcBrooks: No, that can not be the reason for the smoke. The 20AH of your battery is *only* a measure of the capacity, so how long it will last. The amount of power that is flowing is determined by your *load*. A 2A connector is fine, because the 1000C is only able to deliver 2A max. anyway.

Comment: Quote: "it could be some of the components on the board might have their resistance change due to the higher amp current". Well, since there was smoke, this could have happened, but it has nothing to do with the capacity of your battery.

Comment: Quote: "Didn't need to worry about + & - as the connector only allows one way for the pins to meet." But did you check it? Because even though the connector only fits one way, it doesn't mean the wires *inside* the connector can not be reversed anyway. There is no standard as to where the + and the - *in the connector* go...

Comment: Btw, the 1000C info on the website is a bit ambiguous. *"2A internal switch (~2.5A peak limiting) means you can get 1000mA+ from a 3.7V LiPoly/LiIon battery."* - So can it deliver 2A, or 1A+ or how much excactly???

Comment: @MartinF I will give your edit a check and get back to you on how it goes.

Comment: @MartinF It was exactly as you said the polarity of the cables was the opposite way around.

With a little care managed to pop out the connectors and switch opposite way and that worked. Cheers for sticking it out to the end with me over this.

Comment: @MartinF in regards to charging it I will work that out at a later date I plan to probably follow the approach of the likes of anker allowing super fast charging Which should be able to lower the charging time.

Also as this is a prototype the biggest reason why I have 20Ah is cause I have a Cree LED involved in the design at the moment which uses 3000mah plus 1100mah from the other components in my later version I end up removing this. Meaning I have roughly only 1100mah to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, I appreciate it. Glad it worked out well. As the module was on reversed voltage for a short while, keep an eye on it. Sometimes it seems to be working well, but problems occur later, or under certain circumstances. Consider replacing it for the final product or if it starts to behave weird :-). Sounds like an interesting project you're working on! Keep up the good work.

Comment: The idea that such a battery cell provides 3.7 volts is itself substantially mistaken.  Typically a freshly charged lithium polymer pack will be 4.2 volts per cell, though a few are now rated for charge to higher voltages.   Checking that both the design and pack are of the *single cell* variety would however be appropriate.